# Does SVNParentPath accept apache enviroment?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-dav-svn

Does SVNParentPath accept apache enviroment?

I want to configure a svn server with multiple SVNParentPath, how can i set it dynamically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No.  You'd need something akin to `VirtualDocumentRoot`, which mod_dav_svn does not have.

Your best bet may be to programatically generate the config for your `<Location>` blocks.